# C# Find Index of a List of Classes

Tags: c#

Finding an Index of a Class:

The only way I know to find an index of List is

```
        int index = listEmployee.FindIndex(
            delegate(Employee findEmployee)
            {
                return findEmployee.Name.Equals(findName, StringComparison.Ordinal);
            });
```

I was wondering how to add the option to use

```
int indexT = listEmployee.FindIndex(r >= r.Name == findName);
```

Or basically what I'm doing wrong that I can't use it.

```
class Employee
{
    private string _name; private int _idNumber; 
    private string _deptarment; private string _position;

    public Employee()
    {
        _name = ""; _idNumber = 0; _deptarment = ""; _position = "";
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }
    public int IdNumber
    {
        get { return _idNumber; }
        set { _idNumber = value; }
    }
    public string Department
    {
        get { return _deptarment; }
        set { _deptarment = value; }
    }
    public string Position
    {
        get { return _position; }
        set { _position = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you think that you doing something wrong?

Comment: `int indexT = listEmployee.FindIndex(r => r.Name == findName);` is fine

Comment: Your lamdba expression is wrong `r => r.Name == findName`

Comment: Thank you... yeah I had the syntax wrong.  And was struggling on the issue for 30 minutes before finally posting the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was wondering how to add the option to use

```
int indexT = listEmployee.FindIndex(r >= r.Name == findName);
```

That's fine, apart from the syntax problem at `r >=` which should be `r =>`

So this works:

```
int indexT = listEmployee.FindIndex(r => r.Name == findName);
```

See: [Lambda Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx)

Comment: Thanks... /sigh been driving myself nuts and it's a simple syntax error driving me there.

Answer (score 1):

```
int indexT = listEmployee.FindIndex(r => r.Name == findName);
```

should work. Perhaps you are missing the *using System.Linq* referece

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish, but a simple List collection is not going to ensure order or sort, so the index (especially if the collection is going to be expected to change) is not a reliable means of accessing a specific object.

If index / order is important, maybe look at a different collection type, such as the Sorted list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx

If you're just trying to find a specific object, you can use Linq and just go something like:

```
listEmployee.Where( r => r.Name == findName );
```

Comment: Just trying to learn C# ATM for a class project I sorted a list box so I could figure out how to use Find Index command.  Just trying to learn as much as I can.